# How can I change the with and height of the banner in all dialogs using WixUI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I am using Wix 3.8 and a built-in WixUI dialog set called `WixUI_InstallDir`:

```
<UI>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" /> 
</UI>
```

I am using a custom banner in my dialogs:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="images\WixSetupBannerTop.bmp"/>
```

How can I change the width and height of the banner?

Answer (score 1):

WiXUI doesn't support this as a customization.  You'd have to create your own UI or obtain one from somewhere (WiX UI from sources for example).